# Where is the owner of an nft is stored?

Tags: smartcontracts, nft

I know the nft is minting through a smart contract into the blockchain. But where is the owner wallet stored? and also changing the owner requires additionl smart contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Owner address of each token is stored in its collection contract.

The [ERC-721](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md) standard only defines that the owner should be retrievable by calling the `ownerOf()` function, passing it the token ID as the only argument. It doesn't define how exactly the information should be stored.

But many implementations use a `mapping`. For example the OpenZeppelin [implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.4.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L29):

```
mapping(uint256 => address) private _owners;

function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (address) {
    address owner = _owners[tokenId];
    require(owner != address(0), "ERC721: owner query for nonexistent token");
    return owner;
}
```

> *changing the owner requires additionl smart contract?*

Assuming the collection contract follows the standard, it's able to change the token owner (i.e. transfer the token) by executing any of the transfer functions from the owner's (non-contract) address.

So it doesn't require an additional smart contract to transfer a token.